# LISP Programming - function that calculates the nodes of a tree

Tags: tree, lisp, eval, common-lisp

I have recently started learning lisp and completed some simple exercises that are available to me, unfortunately I have got stuck & after spending hours it seems I don't seem to be getting any closer to a decent solution.

I am trying to produce a function which takes the expression 'tree' as its argument and returns the tree with the relevant calculated values in place of the operators.

An example of what a tree could look like is: `(* (+ 10 (* 4 9)) (- 6 10))`
And the function should return: `(-184 (46 10 (36 4 9)) (-4 6 10))`

I have tried all sorts but nothing works as it should. I have created something which works but is really bad in terms of coding style, I really am lost here.

```
(defun evalTree (node &optional n)
  (when node
    (rplaca node (eval node))
    (setq n (first (rest node)))
    (rplaca n (eval n))
    (setq n (first (rest (rest node))))
    (rplaca n (eval n))
    (setq n (first (rest (rest (first (rest node))))))
    (rplaca n (eval n)))
  (format t "node=~a n=~a~%" node n)
  node)
```

I think my solution should be using the apply function or the eval function but im just not sure of how to use them on trees properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun eval-tree (tree)
  (flet ((arg (a)
           (if (atom a) a (first a))))
    (if (atom tree)
        tree
      (destructuring-bind (op a b)
          tree
        (let ((a1 (eval-tree a))
              (b1 (eval-tree b)))
          (list (funcall op (arg a1) (arg b1)) a1 b1))))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, im not quite sure how exactly it works but I will read up on the functions you used and hopefully I will learn from it. Thanks again.